# Utilizar namespace en php

Tags: php, laravel

¿Como puedo usar un namespace en PHP sin hacer un include del archivo (estilo laravel o synfony)?

Ejemplo:

**Cambiar este código:**

```
  namespace fub;
  include 'file1.php';
  include 'file2.php';
  include 'file3.php';

  use foo as feline;
  use bar as canine;
  use other\animate;
```

**Por este código:**

```
  namespace fub;

  use foo as feline;
  use bar as canine;
  use other\animate;
```

Comment: PSR-4 o PSR-0..

Comment: Santiago, tienes algo de tiempo en el sitio, aún no has realizado el [tour] para saber como funcionamos, te sugiero revisar también [ask] y modificar tu pregunta ya que fue reportada como pregunta de "baja calidad", saludos.

Comment: Como mi reputación no es suficiente para responder con un comentario, debo responderte por esta vía.
Consulta [http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.php) allí encuentras todo lo que necesites al respecto. Perdona la amplitud de la respuesta pero no puede ser mejor dada la amplitud de la pregunta.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz PSR-0/4 no es más que una convención que se puede seguir o no, aún que se recomienda. Pero por si solo no proporciona una respuesta. En este caso el OP parece buscar como hacer autoload de clases.

Comment: Precisamente por eso lo puse como comentario y no como respuesta